# Would submerging a 100% waterproof hotspot device increase network connectivity?

Tags: signal, signal-to-noise, waterproof

I have this portable hotspot device (9cm*6cm*1cm*) in which I insert a simcard and keep it within 10m when I am using it. Let us consider that it is water cannot damage it even if I submerge it. Would the internet connection with this new apparature increase? Or would its connectivity with my phone increase? How does this work? I am asking this because once I saw a show on Nat Geo which mentioned that pressing a car signal key against the chin increased the distance upto which it can detect person's car. Let it be known that I won't submerge my device for real as it is not water repellent.

Edit: What about floating the device on water?

Comment: how to you equate touching a car key to a chin with submerging a transmitter in water? .... i could understand testing a bowl of water on top of the hotspot though

Comment: one thing in your question is unclear though ... what is `internet connection increase`? .... what exactly is increasing?

Comment: Floating the device on salt water will introduce a good ground plane and would most likely increase the connectivity.

Comment: @skvery But I want know why that happens?

Comment: Any good ground plane will increase the signal strength.  Salt water is a good, conductive ground plane.

Answer (score 2):

Radio waves are strongly attenuated by water. The higher frequency, the stronger the attenuation. Putting a mobile router underwater will result in drop of all connectivity.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_with_submarines

Comment: Then what about the pressing car key device against chin to improve the signal? Haven't you heard about it? I know there is not submersion there but please reply

Comment: Maybe it acts as a crude reflector (like in a yagi antenna).

Comment: Car key / mouth - probably a ground plane. Yes, it works. Hotspot under water - MUCH worse.

Comment: @user764565 I suspect it would attenuate the signal if you put the keyfob in your mouth and closed your mouth around it.